# Cannot link GitHub to Watson Studio

Tags: github, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I generate a personal access token at GitHub and then under Watson Studio profile settings choose integration. However, when I paste the token I receive a response claiming the token's format is invalid.  Searching in GitHub and the IBM Cloud community returns no similar issues.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below please find an image of the issue.

[Intergration tab under Watson Studio profile settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw0Kg.png)

Answer (score 1):

Good day, public GitHub recently changed their format for personal access tokens. The symptom your are describing stems most likely from the fact, that Watson Studio currently isn't able to deal with the newly introduced format as described by the below resource.

https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I suspected that was the issue but when I checked on the IBM side I couldn't find anything but did have a representative informed me that another person just recently reached out with a similar concern.  Since your response was the most complete, I'll post it on my data science course discussion.  Again, thank you.  It is greatly appreciated.