# Linking Git on Watson Studio issue

Tags: git, github, ibm-watson

I am having an issue when I try to link my Git Personal Access Token on Watson Studio. Keeps on giving this error: **Invalid token format.**

[image: Invalid token format.]

I tried to generate new token but same issue, also checked the internet about the same but did not find resolution for this.

Comment: Do you have any space in your personal access token?

Comment: I checked the token, but it is correct, no spaces are there.
it is like this: ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66973718/372172

Comment: This format is the Classic token. Did the application specified the type of access token? Could they have required the "Fine-grained personal access tokens" (of "github_pat_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" format)?

Comment: This is not a resolution for my issue, I wanted to see if there is a resolution for that. I also tried the Fine-grained personal access tokens and same issue happened.